# Symfony2 form is not valid but entity gets saved anyway?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I couldn't find a solution for my current problem in the web.

I got a formular and an entity.
If the formular is not valid ($form->isValid() returns false), the entity is saved with the invalid data anyway. I see the form errors and that's correct. But my entity should not be updated if the form is not valid. What is going wrong here?
My entity got a hand full fields and a many-to-many relation with extra fields too.

I can show you some code parts:

```
$entry = $em->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Entry')->find($id);

// ...

$form = $this->createForm(new EntryType($this->getUser(), $entry), $entry);

$request = $this->getRequest();

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $form->bind($request);

// ...

// i set custom errors here by myself!

if ($entry->getDeadlineEnable() && NULL === $entry->getDeadlineAt()) {
    $form->get('deadline_at')->addError(new FormError('Please enter a date.'));
}

// ...

if ($form->isValid()) {

    $em->merge($entry);
    $em->flush();

    // ...

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MyAppBundle_homepage'));
```

As you can see, I check the form with isValid, which works correct. It returns false if there is a form error, e.g.

```
$form->get('deadline_at')->addError(new FormError('Please enter a date.'));
```

But the entitiy gets updated exactly here in this line anyway:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
```

Why is this?
This is a really bad problem here. I don't know why this happens.

Thanks for any advice.

---

EDIT:

More information:

I use validators too for all fields wich has simple conditions.
I do this in the EntryType.php @ public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options), e.g.:

```
$builder->add('min_commitments', null, array(
    'label' => 'Zusagen mindestens',
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => 'Ab wievielen findet\'s statt?',
        'min' => 0,
        'max' => 100,
    ),
    'required' => false,
    'invalid_message' => 'Das ist keine gütige Angabe.',
    'constraints' => array(
        new Range(array(
            'minMessage' => 'Mindestens 1.',
            'maxMessage' => 'Maximal 100.',
            'min' => 1,
            'max' => 100,
        )),
    ),
));
```

This is a number field to type in a number between 1 and 100.
But for some fileds i use my own validation direclty in the controller action method because the fields (most of them are a combination of a checkbox field and an text field belonging to to this checkbox) because many fields are interdependent.

I still don't know whats wrong with isValid and why the entity behind this form gets saved even the form is not completely valid. isValid returns false there if an error exists (correct).

Could this maybe be caused by the many to many relation ship?
I implementet such a relationship to allow the user to select many checkboxes, where each checkbox represents an user. The relation rows are saved into the relation table EntryUser.
Here is the many to many field in the form definition (Entry.php):

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntryUser", mappedBy="entry", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $entry_users; // One more thing: this is a one to many but it is a many to many relationship at all because i created a relationship table with extra fields so it bacame a own entity. on the other side, the file User.php got the oppsite part of the many-to-many relationship with:
```

User.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EntryUser" , mappedBy="user" , cascade={"all"} , orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $entry_users;
```

Comment: add $form->getErrors() in statement?

Comment: The form->bind is what is actually updating the entity with posted data regardless of the data's validity.  You must have another flush getting kicked off somewhere.  Perhaps a listener?  Normal workflow for $form->isValid() === false is to redisplay the form with the invalid data and error messages.  Once again, it would appear that you have something calling $em->flush.

Comment: Cerad. I found it. It is caused by a listener, you got right! In a ControllerLister, onKernelController method, i always update the current user object and renews its "activity_at" field! So since the current user is ALWAYS attached to the entity in my scenario, this starts the flushing chain and finally the entity gets updated. So if you write your comment as an official answer, i can mark it as the solution. But let me ask one more question: How can i update the activity_at timestamp in a nicer and working way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The form->bind is what is actually updating the entity with posted
>   data regardless of the data's validity. You must have another flush
>   getting kicked off somewhere. Perhaps a listener? Normal workflow for
>   $form->isValid() === false is to redisplay the form with the invalid
>   data and error messages. Once again, it would appear that you have
>   something calling $em->flush.-
>   Credit to @Cerad

Comment: Just for information: I had a flush in a listener. It got called everytime i refreshed the page. So you got right! Removed/fixed the flush call and all is fine.

Comment: Maybe another solution would be to setup 2 entity managers as said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656366/symfony2-invalid-form-still-saves-entity-on-flush#comment55090818_33656366 Didn't test yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried validators? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

If your attached code is from your controller - the problem is that your condition is wrong.

```
if ($entry->getDeadlineEnable() && NULL === $entry->getDeadlineAt()) {
    $form->get('deadline_at')->addError(new FormError('Please enter a date.'));
}
```

Controller isn't the best place to valide. How are you going to reuse the validator for the form?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes, i use validators too. I updated my question to show you some code snippets. I use validators for fields which have simple conditions. But "deadline_enable" is a checkbox (boolean, checked=true) and the deadline_at (datetime) should only be proofed if this checkbox is checked by the user. So this are filds with are interdependent. But what I saw was that this line if ($entry->getDeadlineEnable() && NULL === $entry->getDeadlineAt()) { works great. So I still wondering why the entity gets saved to the database when isValid() get called.

Comment: Read this http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-a-better-callback-constraint and move validation from controller to model.

Add die('die'); into block of your if condition and tell me what happend!

Comment: Thank you. I have just read it and I will implement it. I'll tell you how it works then. Do i have to move ALL the validations to the Model (including the validations which are currently in the public function buildForm(...) method? Or is it okay to leave the simple validations there and just move the "complex" validations from the controller to the model?

Comment: It's good to keep it in good place instead of random place. Controllers should be as thin as possible.