# Symfony2 invalid form still saves entity on flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I currently have a form and on save I always make an API call to validate the form information against an external source (eg: is the company a VAT paying company etc.). I also want to store in the database the response I get from the external API, for which I have a post submit subscriber on the form.

In the subscriber, I call the API and set errors on the form where values do not match. That is where I call a service to handle all the business logic and somewhere in there I have

```
$em->persist($apiResponse);
$em->flush();
```

to hold onto the API response.

This ends up saving the entity values attached to the form (company) in the database even though these values are actually invalid and the user is returned to the form page saying that.

Please note this happens on edit, and I understand why it happens, because the entity is managed by Doctrine.

I also tried flushing only the entity I am interested in:

```
$em->persist($apiResponse);
$em->flush($apiResponse);
```

and this seems to work, but I read this can have an unexpected behavior.

Hence, my question is: what are the solutions for this ?

Thank you, and sorry for the lack of code samples!

Comment: Unless $apiResponse is an entity that has relations to the entities in your form & cascade on persist set, it shouldn't persist other entities. If your form isn't valid you shouldn't be persisting anything else. I don't see a problem with persisting a single entity at all, but it might be helpful to post your controller code and form class if you're concerned about methodology.

Comment: Consider making two entity managers and reserving one for storing the externel api response.  That will prevent any unintentional updating of your regular entities.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html